# How Do I store rating average in database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi I have just implemented a rating system for myself.
A have 3 model and tables: venue, user, review.
think of venue as a score.
my rating table looks like this:

```
Schema::create('reviews', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->integer('venue_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('venue_id')->references('id')->on('venues')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->tinyInteger('quality');
        $table->tinyInteger('cost');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

#### Here the problem starts

every time a user adds a review for a venue,Laravel `saved` event is fired, I just sum all venues ratings, count all records number, sum venue's ratings,count venue's record numbers and calculate the rating in a **special way** and store venue's rating in an attribute called rating in venues table.
but this seems really inefficient without I just inserted 10000 rows in table in 2min without averaging and 7min with the above method.
How can I store a venues rating in a table and how to update it

Things I have tried but didn't help

1- Caching queries (reduced just 1min)
2- Making a queued job (reduced 3min)

Comment: Don't all your ratings have the same value of rating then? Why don't you simply calculate it when needed, rather than on insert. what if you update/delete?

Comment: @nuzzleman ratings are used for filtering top venues.it's based on laravel saved event . updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why not query the average rating dynamically?

```
$count = \DB::table('ratings')
    ->selectRaw('SELECT AVG(rating) as average_rating')
    ->where('venue', $someVenueId)
    ->get();
```

Comment: I mentioned average is calculated in a special way.

Comment: In which case, you need to use a transaction. Insert all of the records, and then perform the rating calculation *once* - instead of for every record inserted. If you're inserting 10000 every 2 minutes, the rating will be of little value over that period of time so you may as well insert it once, and return the last calculated value at any other time.

Comment: @ohffs I don't think transactions is the right way,I seeded table 10000 records to see efficiency,how does transaction supposed do work in production? does it makes average ,say,for every 5 record creation?

Comment: I think using AVG on bulk records will make it even slower